# How to make an addition instead of a concatenation

Tags: jquery

I have an input button. I created for this input an attribute called "multiplicateur" which has the value of 1. When the button is clicked I have a `.click()` triggered. The function is suppose to get the value of the attribute and add 1 to it. So my output should be 2. Instead the output is 11. It seems the system makes a concatenation instead of an addition.

My HTML:

```
<input id="envoyer" type="submit" multiplicateur=1>
```

My JS:

```
$('#envoyer').click(function() {
    var ajaxData = $(this).attr('multiplicateur');
    alert(ajaxData + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ajaxData` is a `string`. Thus, you need to ***parse*** it to an `integer`...

```
 $('#envoyer').click(function() {
    const ajaxData = $(this).attr('multiplicateur');

    /* parse string to integer */
    alert(parseInt(ajaxData) + 1);

});
```

Comment: You code works but when i test it in JS Fiddle it returns an error (Missing radix parameter). Do you know why?

Comment: @user1162116 It's intriguing your to receiving that error as the second parameter to `parseInt` is optional. Try passing 10 - `parseInt(ajaxData, 10)`

Comment: No error know! Great. What does the second parameter represent?

Comment: @user1162116 the second parameter is the ***radix*** or ***base*** (number of unique digits). I assumed you wanted the common *base 10*

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse it first:

```
    parseInt(ajaxData)+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add value with decimal point, please use parseFloat(ajaxData)

alert(parseFloat(ajaxData) + 1);

Answer (score 0):

For substracting

```
function removeFromQtt(){
             $("qty").value = parseInt($("qty").value)-1;
 }
```

For addition

```
function add(){
             $("qty").value = parseInt($("qty").value)+1;
 }
```