# How can I cycle through HTML select <option> values on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In a calendar app, I have a simple select that has option tag with values 0-11 for the corresponding months. I can cycle through the months one-way (from Dec to Jan), but I can't get it to work going the other way. It only shows Feb and Dec.

Here's [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtJRn/19/) showing what I've already done.

Here's the HTML:

```
<select id="MonthName" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <!-- etc, through 11 -->
</select>

<!-- 'Buttons' -->
<span class="chevron chevronLeft floatLeft">◀</span>
<span class="theMonth">Month</span>
<span class="chevron chevronRight floatRight">▶</span>
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
$('.chevron').on('click', function() {
  // This if works perfectly, and will reset to 11 once the selectedMonth is 0
  if ($(this).hasClass('chevronLeft')) {
    var selectedMonth = $('#MonthName').val();
    (selectedMonth != 0) 
      ? $('#MonthName').val(selectedMonth - 1).trigger('change')
      : $('#MonthName').val(11).trigger('change');
  }

  else {
    // This doesn't work, I tried declaring the variable locally, 
    // different less/greater than expressions, but nothing works
    var selectedMonth = $('#MonthName').val();
    (selectedMonth !== 11)
      ? $('#MonthName').val(selectedMonth + 1).trigger('change')
      : $('#MonthName').val(0).trigger('change');
  }
});

$('#MonthName').on('change', function() {
   var monthText = 
    $('#MonthName option:selected').text();
    $('.theMonth').text(monthText);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
var selectedMonth = $('#MonthName').val();
```

to:

```
var selectedMonth = parseInt($('#MonthName').val(), 10);
```

`selectedMonth + 1` was doing string concatenation instead of integer addition because `selectedMonth` was a string.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/mtJRn/20/)

I also suggest you specify the width of `theMonth` -- it's difficult clicking on the right arrow because it keeps moving as the month changes.

Comment: Question though — I tried casting the selectedMonth var to a Number and I must have removed it so I can't replicate it perfectly, something like `$('#MonthName').val(Number(selectedMonth + 1))` —   would that not do the same thing?  I'm sure I could definitely have the syntax wrong!  And why did it work when I was going towards January but not when I was going to December?

Comment: You need to cast the variable, not the result of the addition: `.val(Number(selectedMonth)+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are concatenating an int to and a string.

Doing for example `'1' + 1` will equal `11` and not `2`. Parse your value before the addition :

```
$('#MonthName').val(parseInt(selectedMonth) + 1)
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mtJRn/21/

Comment: You also needed to change `!==` to `!=` because the types are different.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Feb and Dec correspond to 1 and 11, so you are not adding numeric values but concatenating strings.

For your reference, here's a question may suit your problem:
[How to make an addition instead of a concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081630/how-to-make-an-addition-instead-of-a-concatenation)

As a side note, when I was attending the primary school my teacher used to say:

> "You cannot add apples and pears."

Well, in javascript you can, because it is [weakly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing).